# Disable HTTP Cache on Android React Native

Tags: react-native, axios, fetch

Is there any way to avoid storing api request and response in http_cache on Android rooted device.

I have already tried 'cache-control' but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

OkHttp controls caching. If you want to disable caching, set `cacheSize=0` in

```
node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/network/OkHttpClientProvider.java
```

Comment: Pay attention: changes in node_modules will not stored in the Git repository. You can use patch-package to save these changes.